# Is there a case or cover that allows the iPad to stand up in portrait orientation?

Tags: hardware-recommendation, ipad, smart-cover

Is there a cover that is designed for standing up the iPad 3 in portrait as well as in landscape orientation? I'm not talking about the Apple official Smart Cover. Something, possibly, in leather.

Comment: Hi. What do you mean bt "as well"? As well as what?

Comment: As well as horizontal?

Comment: I always see it horizontal in the pictures.

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically want a case then the CaseCrown flip case is a good option: http://www.amazon.com/s?ie=UTF8&x=11&ref_=nb_sb_noss&y=19&field-keywords=casecrown%20Genuine%20leather%20vertical%20flip%20ipad%20case&url=search-alias%3Delectronics

However, if you really just want a stand then Twelve South makes the excellent Compass which does both portrait and landscape: http://www.twelvesouth.com/products/compass/gallery/

I have a Compass and I love it.

I also have a Twelve South Book Arc for my desk at home: http://www.twelvesouth.com/products/bookarc_ipad/gallery/

The Book Arc is heavy so you wouldn't carry it around, but it's great for a desk.

Comment: I have the Compass stand and the back leg has always been too loose and the iPad falls over fairly easily in Portrait mode if you tap on the top quarter of the screen.

Comment: +1 I can second the Twelve South recommendations, and the Compass is small enough to carry around in addition to a cover. @MarkThalman - Their products usually seem well built. Have you asked about an exchange to fix the back leg?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to place the iPad 3 in the vertical position, the first option is buy a stand for it. As you have asked for the case, then there are some cases that come with a stand. The [crocodile leather plus stand case](http://www.ipad3casestore.net/crocodile-genuine-leather-stand-for-ipad-3/) could be the right choice for you. It is built with leather and has a stand too. The black, white, and other colors are available. Hope this will helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

The Moshi Versa origami case is great. It has a hard plastic back case and a thin cover that folds to allow the iPad to stand vertically (for portrait viewing, ideal for reading books) or horizontally (for landscape viewing, ideal for watching video). It also folds to make a 40 degree angle for typing.